# android says: DexOpt: couldn't find static field

Tags: java, android

when i launch my app i get this error in some devices, it works on 90% of devices:

```
10-04 03:25:36.221: D/dalvikvm(889): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
10-04 03:25:36.221: W/dalvikvm(889): VFY: unable to resolve static field 33 (THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) in Landroid/os/AsyncTask;
10-04 03:25:36.221: D/dalvikvm(889): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
10-04 03:25:36.221: D/dalvikvm(889): VFY: dead code 0x0010-0014 in Lcom/app/weatherclock/MainActivity$10;.run ()V
10-04 03:25:37.572: W/webcore(889): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
10-04 03:25:37.622: W/dalvikvm(889): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x405d4ae8 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
10-04 03:25:37.652: I/dalvikvm(889): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
10-04 03:25:37.652: I/dalvikvm(889):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40542478 self=0x2cc748
10-04 03:25:37.652: I/dalvikvm(889):   | sysTid=897 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2934912
10-04 03:25:37.652: I/dalvikvm(889):   | schedstat=( 512988197 618674688 90 )
10-04 03:25:37.652: I/dalvikvm(889):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeFinished(Native Method)
 10-04 03:25:37.652: I/dalvikvm(889):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeFinished(Native Method)
10-04 03:25:37.661: I/dalvikvm(889):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.tearDown(LoadListener.java:1200)
10-04 03:25:37.661: I/dalvikvm(889):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleEndData(LoadListener.java:721)
10-04 03:25:37.661: I/dalvikvm(889):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:219)
10-04 03:25:37.661: I/dalvikvm(889):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 03:25:37.661: I/dalvikvm(889):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-04 03:25:37.672: I/dalvikvm(889):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
10-04 03:25:37.681: I/dalvikvm(889):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

what is the problem? i cant understand

Comment: Did you notice any commonalities of the devices that don't work? For example the same Android version or the same manufacturer?

Comment: @Henry yes i have. i have many reports from galaxy s , xperia x10 and...

Comment: Did u find a solution?